# Matrix transformation

Tags: matrix

Let an expression $X^T AX+B^TX$, how can I transform it as $Y^T C Y$; where $Y=[X, 1]$, find $C$ in terms of $A$ and $B$ using Mathematica?

Comment: $C=A+(X^t)^{-1}B^t$?

Comment: C will be only in term of A and B.

Comment: Impossible. Your first expression has non-zero derivative at `X=0`, while your second does not. They are not equal, unless $C=C(X)$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform edited.

Comment: What does $[X,1]$ mean?

Comment: X is a matrix of size $1 \times N$, Y is $1\times (N+1)$, i.e., 1 is added with X.

Comment: $$C=\begin{pmatrix}A&\frac12B\\\frac12B^t&0\end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform is there any way to obtain it using Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform  your answer is correct. Can you suggest a way to find it using Mathematica?